# Strange iOS 8 auto layout issue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios8, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell.

1. Initially some subviews and some auto layout constraints are set on the content view of the cell. Everything works as expected.
2. Then I programmatically change (remove/add) some subviews and completely reset constraints (remove all, then add new constraints). After that, UITable containing the cell is refreshed (row's height is recalculated) and *setNeedsUpdateContraints*, *updateConstraintsIfNeeded* are also called explicitly on the cell.

Here is the complete code to reproduce the issue. It's in C# (Xamarin), but it's easy to read the idea. [Here is](https://gist.github.com/alxbog/bc60f3f57ecb06b2cebf) almost the same code in Swift.

```
public class TableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var source = new TableSource(TableView);

        var updateButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Update", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (s, args) => source.DoUpdate());
        NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = updateButton;

        TableView.Source = source;
        TableView.ReloadData();
    }
}

public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly UITableView _tableView;
    private readonly TableCell _cell;

    public TableSource(UITableView tableView)
    {
        _tableView = tableView;
        _cell = new TableCell();
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return _cell;
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 55.0f;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public void DoUpdate()
    {
        _cell.DoUpdate();
        _tableView.ReloadData();
    }
}

public class TableCell : UITableViewCell
{
    private UILabel _label;

    public TableCell()
    {
        DoUpdate();
    }

    public void DoUpdate()
    {
        foreach (var subview in ContentView.Subviews)
        {
            subview.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }

        _label = new UILabel {Text = "Text here"};
        ContentView.Add(_label);

        foreach (var subview in ContentView.Subviews)
        {
            subview.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        }

        ContentView.RemoveConstraints(ContentView.Constraints);
        ContentView.AddConstraints(
            new[]
            {
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_label, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, 15.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_label, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1.0f, 100.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_label, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 20.0f),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(_label, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, ContentView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, -20.0f)
            });
    }
}
```

On launch everything works fine:

[image]

But after clicking Update button (resetting subviews and constraints):

On **iOS 7** nothing changes (works as expected).

On **iOS 8** layout doesn't work as expected. It looks like it loses some constraints defining margins between some of subviews and cell's content view borders:

[image]

Any ideas why this happens? It looks like a bug in iOS auto layout system.

Comment: Are you implementing the heightForRowAtIndexPath method? A screenshot or drawing would be nice to understand exactly the layout problem you're facing.

Comment: Yes, implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath. Added screenshots, thanks.

Comment: Please show your code that creates the constraints.

Comment: You don't need to use RevealApp any more. Xcode 6 has swallowed it. :)

Comment: @matt, added dump of all constraints.

Comment: @matt, I'm using Xamarin so it's not yet shallowed RevealApp :)

Comment: That's great but what I asked to see is your code. You see, the meaning of certain expressions in a constraint string has changed in iOS 8 and I want to see if you are using any of those expressions. So I need to see how you are actually making the constraints.

Comment: Okay, well, he who lives by the third-party-framework-that-gets-between-you-and-the-API, dies by the third-party-framework-that-gets-between-you-and-the-API. Basically this is between you and xamarin, whatever that is. I mean, yes, auto layout _has_ changed in iOS 8, because there are now `layoutMargins`, but what xamarin may or may not know about that is anyone's guess.

Comment: @matt, the problem is not in Xamarin. I've created Swift sample that reproduces the issue here: https://gist.github.com/alxbog/bc60f3f57ecb06b2cebf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iOS 8 AutoLayout now **really** defines margins.

**UPDATED**

You break `contentView` constraints by doing this:

```
ContentView.RemoveConstraints(ContentView.Constraints);
```

This line breaks `contentView` relations with its parent. Remove this line.

Comment: All constraints are created in code, so I'm not using margin related constraints.

Comment: @alexey, though, `|-[subview]-|` gives you **relative to margin**. Try `|[subview]|` instead. And check `layoutMargins` property of `UIView`.

Comment: I guess the string description contains '-'s because of Xamarin implementation. I'm for sure define all constraints using NSLayoutAttribute and never use new iOS 8 type of attributes.

Comment: @alexey, ok, I see. So I can recommend you to contact lib creator at first. Then change you code, to use different values for iOS8/pre-iOS8 versions. Some kinda workaround.

Comment: @orkenstrein, completely updated the question. Now the sample is much simplier. Also removed any dependencies on libs. So libs are not a problem.

Comment: @alexey, `NSLayoutConstraint.Create(...)` is defined in **Xamarin**. So the problem is **Xamarin** then. Use native function `
constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:`.

Comment: @alexey, have you checked your `view.layoutMargins` value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63147/discussion-between-alexey-and-orkenstein).

Comment: Removing constraints was a real issue. Thx.